# Can't get response from MS CRM 2016 API on premise

Tags: php, api, odata, dynamics-crm-2016

We are using dynamics crm 2016 in-premise using IFD. I am using below code to get a lead from CRM using API in php

```
//$url = $crm_url . "XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/LeadSet($lead)";
$url = $crm_url . "api/data/v8.1/leads($lead)";

 $headers = array(
      'Method: GET',
        'OData-MaxVersion: 4.0',
        'OData-Version: 4.0',
      'Connection: keep-alive',
      'User-Agent: PHP-SOAP-CURL',
      'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'Accept: application/json',
      'Host: ' . $host);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if( $response === false) { echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);}
$status = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );echo "Status: $status ";
$response=json_decode($response, true);
foreach ($response as $id) {
                    $guid = $id['LeadId'];                  
                    echo 'GUID: ' . $guid. ' ';
                }
echo "Lead id: "; var_dump($response['LeadId']);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
echo "</pre>";
curl_close($ch);
```

I am getting this response:

```
Status: 401 GUID: T GUID: GUID: Lead id: NULL
Array
    (
        [Message] => There was an error processing the request.
        [StackTrace] => 
        [ExceptionType] => 
    )
```

Can someone please help me how to get the correct response. 
Alse please let me know if there is another method.
Many thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the leadid is not filled in your request.

> $url = $crm_url . "api/data/v8.1/leads(**$lead**)";

Did you replace that variable by the guid?

> exemple:
>   https://contoso.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.1/accounts(1e3983e8-7894-e511-80db-3863bb2e3248)

Also, a good trick to test your queries is to paste them into your browser. I use Chrome. With IE you need to disable the RSS feed.

Sorry, i'm not familliar with php.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I placed that variable with guid. It shows me the lead records if I put this api in chrome but not showing in code. we are using crm 2016 on premise with adfs authentication. Problem is I can't authenticate. giving 404 error